# XLSX Writer Format Disabled By Other Format

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Given the following code, my goal was to center the content in column A vertically. This worked fine until I added the last bit of code, which adds bottom borders but somehow disables the formatting above for column A.

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b','b'],
               'b':['a','b','c','d'],
               'c':[1,2,3,4]})
d=d.groupby(['a','b']).sum()

pd.core.format.header_style = None

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_align('center')
format.set_align('vcenter')
worksheet.set_column('A:C',5, format)

#This seems to disable what I have above for alignment.
formatgbs = workbook.add_format()
formatgbs.set_bottom(7)
for i in np.arange(4):
    worksheet.set_row(i,15,formatgbs)
writer.save()
```

Is there a way to make these two "play nice"?

Thanks in advance!